# Need advice on mail server backup

Tags: email, backup

I'm wondering how I can back up a mail server on IBM 1U with 2x2TB disk. No more slot is left. Should I do RAID or is there any other better idea?

In case the mail server has been used to store mail up to 1 TB. The other HD is used for cloud file sharing. Can we do something to back up from here without interupting everyday use much?

I desperately need your advice and thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

When doing a backup you *never ever* backup towards the same machine. Your backup should be towards another machine, preferably in another geographical location than where your current server is located.

Also refer to: [Why is RAID not a backup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup)

and some general advice on how you *should* do backups here http://blog.serverfault.com/category/backup/

If your hardware can't cope with it anymore, invest money in new hardware or in an external remote backup service.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm rather a newbie. The link you gave is very useful.